# Is there any painting in art history that depicts furniture floating in the air?

Tags: art, painting

Does anyone know if there is any painting in art history that depicts furniture floating in the air?

I searched some catalogues and online encyclopedias that covered the period of 1920-1960, but didn't find any depiction of the kind. It would be really helpful if anyone could name a particular painting.

Comment: Floating in water or floating in the air? Where have you looked already?

Comment: Does a rocking horse count as furniture? https://www.everypainterpaintshimself.com/article/carringtons_self_portrait_c.1937_8

Comment: @BrianZ Surely, thanks a lot!

Comment: Can it be a [photograph](https://www.artsy.net/article/artsy-editorial-story-surreal-photograph-salvador-dali-three-flying-cats)?

Comment: How about a table resting on a floating apple? https://www.artnet.com/artists/ren%C3%A9-magritte/les-belles-r%C3%A9alit%C3%A9s-7px7pBuv9jTAtXMXHpHCpQ2

Comment: I supose a crucifix doesn't count as furniture. If it did, https://www.salvador-dali.org/ca/obra/cataleg-raonat-pintures/obra/667/el-crist

Comment: Things that don't float in air floating in air is kind of a staple of Surealist Art. Try George Grie's *Castle In The Sky* and *Infinite Improbability Drive*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

René Magritte's [*Le Temps menaçant (Threatening Weather)*](https://web.archive.org/web/20231026184829/https://www.masterworksfineart.com/artists/rene-magritte/lithograph/le-temps-menacant-threatening-weather/id/W-5689) depicts a marble torso, a tuba, and what I would call a "kitchen chair" (a wooden chair with wicker seat), all in greyish white, hovering above a deep blue cove and a rocky beach.

[image: a marble torso, a tuba, and a wooden chair with wicker seat, all in greyish white, hovering above a deep blue cove and a rocky beach]

Another image at the [National Galleries Scotland](https://web.archive.org/web/20231026185302/https://www.nationalgalleries.org/art-and-artists/38159).

Comment: I suppose a lithograph isn't technically a painting, but good find!

Comment: I'm flagging this answer because it is not a pipe.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I might be.

Answer (score 6):

If we're accepting non-painting artworks, there's always Phillipe Halsman's [famous photo](https://www.magnumphotos.com/arts-culture/art/philippe-halsman-salvador-dali-enduring-partnership/) of Salvadore Dali *Dali Atomicus*

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There is the [The Absinthe Drinker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Absinthe) by Degas, where the tables are somewhat missing support. For me it always represented the state of mind of the drinker, somehow at that stage you don't really care about such mundane things :).
It may look as if there was some support hidden somewhere in the shades, but even the French version of the Wikipedia page [suggests](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Absinthe#Un_vice_cach.C3.A9) the legs are missing.

[image: d]

Comment: I'd have expected drinkers to *very much* care whether tables are supported...

Comment: after a glass of absinthe, you dont care about nothing. i guess thats the purpose of the drink :).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what you mean by "in art history".

There's a large mural in Boise, Idaho, US of a floating chair.

"In 2017, Spokane’s David Carmack Lewis painted the first of three murals downtown, each one bigger and bolder than the last. The first went up on the Watercooler apartments on Idaho St. and spans a 50-foot by 40-foot wall. Called The Big Back Yard, Lewis’ work shows a chair floating in the sky over a dark desert highway with a single set of taillights in the distance." -- https://boisedev.com/news/2022/08/28/from-freak-alley-to-building-backsides-boises-mural-trend-keeps-growing/

There's a 2017 interview with the artist online via a local new station at https://idahonews.com/news/local/whats-with-the-chair

[image]